# popen() call on Linux, what this lines do?

Tags: c, linux

I am new to system programming, and happen to go through the `popen()` call. This is code snippet of `popen()` implementation on Linux.

`dup2()` call will close the later argument, and the former argument is being explicitly closed in child. Looks like both the descriptors are closed in child.

Why is this thing still working? I am not able to understand the working of the code.

```
switch (pid = vfork()) {
 case -1:            /* error */
     (void) close(pdes[0]);
     (void) close(pdes[1]);
     return (NULL);
     /* NOTREACHED */
 case 0:             /* child */
     if (*type == 'r') {
         if (pdes[1] != fileno(stdout)) {
             (void) dup2(pdes[1], fileno(stdout));
             (void) close(pdes[1]);
         }
         (void) close(pdes[0]);
     } else {
         if (pdes[0] != fileno(stdin)) {
             (void) dup2(pdes[0], fileno(stdin));
             (void) close(pdes[0]);
         }
         (void) close(pdes[1]);
     }
     execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", program, NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

`dup2` means ***dup***licate a file descriptor **to**. `dup2(pdes[1], fileno(stdout));`  As the Linux dup2(2) manual pages say:

> dup2() makes newfd be the copy of oldfd, closing newfd first if necessary

Thus these 2 lines

```
(void) dup2(pdes[1], fileno(stdout));
(void) close(pdes[1]);
```

first close the old stdout file descriptor, then *copy* the pipe endpoint `pdes[1]` to the stdout file descriptor - now there are **2** file descriptors pointing to the same pipe. Then we close the original pipe end point, but the copied one remains opened.

---

BTW, strictly, `fileno(stdout)` is not correct. It returns the file number that the `FILE *stdout` is wrapping, **if it is opened at all**. Instead you should use `STDOUT_FILENO` or `0` there.

Comment: Thanks @Antti . Clear with the concept now.